# Adding user_agent in read_html Inside of a Function

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr, rvest, httr

**Problem:** I'm trying to scrape multiple tables, but am getting the message *"It appears your browser may be outdated..."* inside of my scraped tables.

**Attempts to Fix:** I tried adding a user_agent call inside my read_html() to bypass the issue, but it doesn't seem to change the end result.

**Questions:** How can I bypass an outdated browser with my user_agent call? Am I placing the user_agent call inside my function in the wrong location?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(openxlsx)

#leaderboard links
df6 <- expand.grid(
  tournament_id = c("the-american-express","wm-phoenix-open","farmers-insurance-open"),
  year_id = c("2004", "2005", "2006")
) %>% 
  mutate(
    links = paste0(
      'https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/',
      tournament_id,
      "/past-results.",
      year_id,
      '.html'
    )
  ) %>% 
  as_tibble()


#Scrape function
get_info <- function(link, tournament) {
  link %>%
    read_html(, user_agent ="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36")   %>%
  html_table() %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    clean_names() %>%
    mutate(tournament = tournament)
}

#retrieve data
test501 <- df6 %>%
  mutate(tables = map2(links, tournament_id, possibly(get_info, otherwise = tibble())))

test501 <- test501 %>% 
  unnest(everything())

test501
```

Comment: You could try `link %>% httr::GET(user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36")) %>% read_html() %>% ...etc`

Comment: Thanks for your fast response @AllanCameron - I added this line of code, but am still getting a table with variables that read ""It appears your browser may be outdated..."

Are there times where you just can't pull data from certain sites?

Comment: Yes, many websites these days use javascript to populate their tables dynamically, so the data is simply not present in the raw html you request. Your browser takes the raw html, runs the javascript, and this pulls the data from the server (often in json format) using further http requests. The javascript then parses the json and populates the table. If the website has an API you can get the data directly rather than webscraping. It's often possible to find the XHR request in your browser's development panel (F12). If you post the actual URL, I can see if this is possible here.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @AllanCameron - here is one of the url's I'm pulling:

https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/wm-phoenix-open/past-results.2005.html

Comment: Yes, so those results should be available to scrape on `https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/wm-phoenix-open/past-results/jcr:content/mainParsys/pastresults.selectedYear.2005.003.html` using your normal scraping tools

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron for all of your guidance. I updated the scrape to include the recommended url format.  For some reason - I'm just getting blanks on the pulled info.

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron for showing me how to get the alternate website format. This is super helpful!

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks a ton - I needed to update my version of R and it was causing issues seeing how your recommended url helped get me towards solving my issues. Thanks for the lesson on looking for ways to get at the raw html data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect to see where the data actually comes from using browser dev tools network tab. You need a different url construction then some column and row cleaning. I have not cleaned absolutely everything but given a good number of examples

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(rvest)


# leaderboard links
df6 <- expand.grid(
  tournament_id = c("the-american-express", "wm-phoenix-open", "farmers-insurance-open"),
  year_id = c("2004", "2005", "2006")
) %>%
  mutate(
    links = paste0(
      "https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/",
      tournament_id,
      "/past-results/jcr:content/mainParsys/pastresults.selectedYear.",
      year_id,
      ".html"
    )
  ) %>%
  as_tibble()


# Scrape function
get_info <- function(link, tournament) {
  link %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_element("[data-display-rounds]") %>%
    html_table(trim = T) %>%
    clean_names() %>%
    mutate(tournament = tournament)
}

# retrieve data
test501 <- df6 %>%
  mutate(tables = map2(links, tournament_id, possibly(get_info, otherwise = tibble())))

test501 <- test501 %>%
  unnest(everything())

test501 <- filter(test501, !grepl("PLAYER", player)) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("rounds"), ~ trimws(unlist(str_split(.x, " "))[1])),
  )

test501$pos <- lapply(test501$pos, function(x) tail(unlist(str_split(x, ' ')) ,1))
```

Comment: Thanks @QHarr - This is helpful. I will look into browser dev tools network tab. 

I'm getting a prompt that says could not find the function "across". I this happening to you as well?

Comment: should come in with tidyverse. Otherwise import dpylr  and/or prefix dplyr::across https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html

Comment: Thank you very much @QHarr - I needed to update R as my tidyverse had become outdated. Everything works like a charm!!! All the best